# Response.OutputStream not working in the Asp.net web api core. Is any alternative for it?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

While migrating  .NET Core  Response.OutputStream not working properly. I have using the following code.

```
public void GenerateExcelFromDatatable(DataTable excelTable, string fileName)
{
    var myLogger = new Logger();
    var a = 0;
    var b = 0;
    try
    {
        DataTable stringTable = new DataTable();
        string myExcelFileName = "ExcelFile.xlsx";
        if ((fileName != null) && (fileName != string.Empty))
        {
            myExcelFileName = fileName;
        }
        foreach (DataColumn dc in excelTable.Columns)
        {
            stringTable.Columns.Add(dc.ColumnName, typeof(string));

        }

        for (int i = 0; i < excelTable.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            a = i;
            DataRow myRow = stringTable.NewRow();
            for (int j = 0; j < excelTable.Columns.Count; j++)
            {
                b = j;
                string x = string.Empty;
                x = Convert.ToString(excelTable.Rows[i][j]);
                if (x != null && x != string.Empty)
                {
                    // myRow[j] = MeasureBL.DecodeFrom64(x);

                    myRow[j] = AesHelper.Decrypt256(x);
                }

            }
            stringTable.Rows.Add(myRow);
        }

        //var dataRow = stringTable.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<string>("Physician NPI") == "1528286911").ToList();
        // var NPIMatchingRecord = getNPIMatchingRecordFromDataTable(stringTable,CurrentUser.UserId);


        using (XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook())
        {
            wb.Worksheets.Add(stringTable, "MIPS Excel Data");

            Response.Clear();
            Response.Buffer = true;
            Response.Charset = "";
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + myExcelFileName + ";");
            using (MemoryStream MyMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                wb.SaveAs(MyMemoryStream);
                MyMemoryStream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
                Response.Flush();
                Response.End();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        myLogger.LogError("Error in Measure Controller:GenerateExcelFromDatatable() FileName:[" + fileName + "] of Row:[" + Convert.ToString(a) + "] and Column:[" + Convert.ToString(b) + "]");
    }
}
```

In the above code, I have fixed problems on Response.AddHeader and remaining Reponse properties changes.  Any one know help me if any alternative functionality exists ?

Comment: Your current approach looks in general not so bad, so the question would be: What problems do you have? I think you don't need the additional MemoryStream and would expect that you can simply `SaveAs(Response.OutputStream)` - not tested.

Comment: I have problem with the following error:   Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1061 'HttpResponse' does not contain a definition for 'OutputStream' and no accessible extension method 'OutputStream' accepting a first argument of type 'HttpResponse' could be found

Comment: Ah, I see. OutputStream is .net framework 4.x (not core). In asp.net core use `Body` instead, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httpresponse.body?view=aspnetcore-3.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Http_HttpResponse_Body